# With sqlsrv, INSERT...OUTPUT, sqlsrv_num_rows returns -1?

Tags: php, sql-server, php-7, sql-server-2016, sqlsrv

I have an existing application like the following:

```
//create table test_table( id int identity, n int )
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>$Database, "UID"=>$User, "PWD"=>$Password);
$Conn = sqlsrv_connect( $Server, $connectionInfo) ;
if ( $Conn === false )
    {
    print "*** CONNECTION FAILED for database $Database, user $User, server $Server ***" ;
    die() ;
    }
sqlsrv_configure( 'WarningsReturnAsErrors', 0 ) ;
$params = array();
$options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
$ExecutedCommand = sqlsrv_query( $Conn, "insert test_table output inserted.id values( 123 )", $params, $options ) ;
//$ExecutedCommand = sqlsrv_query( $Conn, "select count(*) from test_table", $params, $options ) ;
if ( $ExecutedCommand === false )
    {
    print "*** COMMAND FAILED ***\n" ;
    print_r( sqlsrv_errors() ) ;
    die() ;
    }
print "rows=" . sqlsrv_num_rows( $ExecutedCommand ) . "\n" ;
print_r( sqlsrv_fetch_array( $ExecutedCommand ) ) ;
```

The idea is to insert a row, and output the newly inserted identity value, to create some child records.
The output is really surprising:

```
rows=-1
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [id] => 4
)
```

In other words, the sqlsrv_fetch_array is returning the expecting result, but the problem is that sqlsrv_num_rows returns -1, like it does in case of error.
If I replace the INSERT..OTPUT with, for instance, a SELECT statement (see commented out row) everything works well.
Please note that if I do:

```
$ExecutedCommand = sqlsrv_query( $Conn, "insert test_table values( 123 )", $params, $options ) ;
$ExecutedCommand = sqlsrv_query( $Conn, "select n=SCOPE_IDENTITY()", $params, $options ) ;
```

The problem still persists. However, if the problem does *not* appear if I do:

```
$ExecutedCommand = sqlsrv_query( $Conn, "insert test_table values( 123 )", $params, $options ) ;
$ExecutedCommand = sqlsrv_query( $Conn, "select n=SCOPE_IDENTITY() INTO #t", $params, $options ) ;
$ExecutedCommand = sqlsrv_query( $Conn, "select n FROM #t", $params, $options ) ;
```

Do you have any idea what is happening?
Details:
PHP 7.0.9 (cli) (built: Jul 20 2016 11:08:23) ( ZTS )
Windows 10
SQL Server 2016
sqlsrv, info from php -i:

```
sqlsrv support => enabled
ExtensionVer => 4.0.8629.2

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
sqlsrv.ClientBufferMaxKBSize => 10240 => 10240
sqlsrv.LogSeverity => 0 => 0
sqlsrv.LogSubsystems => 0 => 0
sqlsrv.WarningsReturnAsErrors => On => On
```

Comment: Please note that if I do:

Comment: Can you try `sqlsrv_rows_affected`?